# ubuntu chrome issues hardware acceleration

Tags: google-chrome, hardware-acceleration

After applying an automatic ubuntu update, Chrome went bonkers. Does not show most images, many icons are empty. Even input field borders not showing. I have found a workaround which was to disable hardware acceleration in Chrome settings. Now everything looks good. Anyone else run into this and is there a better fix available?

Ubuntu: 22.04.2 LTS

Chrome: Version 113.0.5672.126 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Lenovo Idea Pad 3 Core I5

PS. I cleared cache, tried Incognito, rebooted, and all of the other suggested options ... only disabling hardware acceleration worked.

Comment: Try the following Reset Chrome settings: You can try resetting Chrome settings to their default values. In the Chrome settings, look for the "Advanced" section and find the option to reset settings. Note that this will remove any customizations you've made to Chrome. Disable other Chrome extensions: Some Chrome extensions may conflict with certain updates or cause display issues. Try disabling all extensions temporarily to see if the problem persists. If the issue is resolved, re-enable the extensions one by one to identify the culprit.

Comment: Seems to be a winner.  I actually didn't get to the extensions.  I did the reset, restarted chrome, enabled hardware, restarted chrome again ... and I appear to be good.  Thanks

Comment: @nork You should make this an answer so we can accept it, resetting chrome (I actually did it by renaming the google-chrome folder under .config) saved me from having to roll back to a previous version of Ubuntu, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was to reset chrome settings.  I did this, shut down and restarted (don't recall if that part was necessary) and it was working.  I did not have to mess with extensions.  So in my case, the weirdness in Chrome was resolved by resetting chrome settings.

Answer (score 6):

Clearing the cache in `.config/google-chrome/Default/GPUCache` works for me.

Refer: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/217547429/google-chrome-is-not-loading-properly-on-ubunty-22-04

Comment: This also worked for me, and it also fixed any webview apps that had issues. Originally my issue came from a corruption that the Slack app had, and it broke Chrome. Deleting the cache not only fixed Chrome but it also fixed the Slack app!

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue by resetting only chrome flags.

```
chrome://flags > Reset all
```

The strange part is that none of the flags were marked as changed by me but resetting them somehow fixed the issue.